# Express the distribution function Y = max{X, 0} in terms of the distribution function of X.

Tags: probability-theory

This is just asking for a general case, with general distribution of X. I treated it similar to a minimum problem and said that F(y) is P(x >= 0) for x > 0, P(x = 0) for x = 0 and 0 if 0 > x. Is this the right track?

Comment: Your attempt makes little sense and it does not make proper use of the definition of the cumulative distribution function. Let $F_X$ be the cdf of $X$, then what is $F_Y$, the cdf of $Y$?

Answer (score 1):

If $\Pr[ X < 0] = 0$, then $Y = X$, so that case is trivial.

Suppose $\Pr[X < 0] > 0$.  Then we have $$\Pr[Y = 0] = \Pr[X \le 0] = F_X(0).$$  Furthermore, for $y > 0$, $$\Pr[Y \le y] = \Pr[\max(X,0) \le y] = \Pr[X \le y] = F_X(y),$$ because if $X < 0$, then it is also the case that $X < y$ since $y > 0$; and if $X > 0$, then $\max(X,0) = X$.

Therefore, the CDFs of $X$ and $Y$ are the same over the interval $[0,\infty)$, but all the probability mass for $X < 0$ is concentrated into a discrete mass at $Y = 0$.  In effect, we would write $$F_Y(y) = \begin{cases} F_X(y), & y \ge 0 \\ 0, & y < 0. \end{cases}.$$