# The CDF of a Uniform Distribution given $Y=X$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable with pdf

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2}, & \text{if } -1 \leq x \leq 1 \\ 0, & \text{elsewhere} \end{cases} $$

Consider the following random variable $Y$ as

$$ Y = \begin{cases} x, & \text{if } x \geq 0 \\ 0, & \text{if } x < 0 \end{cases} $$

Find the cdf of $Y$.

My attempt:

$$F_Y(y) = P(Y\le y) = P(x\le y) = F_X(y) = \begin{cases} 0,&\text{if } y<-1 \\  \frac{1}{2}{y}+\frac{1}{2}, & \text{if } -1 \leq y < 1 \\ 1, & \text{if } y\geq1 \end{cases}$$

Am I on the right path?

Comment: The answer here should help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1202936/express-the-distribution-function-y-maxx-0-in-terms-of-the-distribution-fun.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, what would be the support of $F_Y(y)$? would th interval be y>0 and y<0?